# Get Files In Project Folder

Tags: c#

I have an Images folder in my visual studio project.

How can I reference the images within this folder so I can use the .exe file on other computers?

Ultimately I am trying to do the following (obviously replacing "Images/image1.jpg" with imageFile).

```
foreach (string imageFile in imageFolder)
{
   ImageSource imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/image1.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Using something like:

```
Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName
```

doesn't work because the .exe could be running in any location.

Comment: So you're asking how to find out the location of your project folder without hard-coding the absolute path? Are you sure that's worth the effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to add or remove such images during the installation of the application on the user's computer, add the images to the resources by dragging them to the Resources tab in the project properties and reference them using `Properties.Resources` within your code.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using copying the image folder to the output of your application and taking the folder with you to the new computers you could use

```
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
```

If you don't have lots of large images, why not include them as embedded resources. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292

Answer (score 0):

Keep images (and other resources) together with exe-file (either in the same folder, which is simplest, or use directory structure).

To example:

```
\Bin
    my.exe
    my.pdb
\Help
    my.html
\Resources
    1.jpg
    2.jpg
```

Then you can so something like

```
    private static string PathRoot { get { return Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)); } }
    public static string PathResources { get { return Path.Combine(PathRoot, "Resources"); } }
```